# Error when installing SQL express server on windows 10

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows

I have Attached the images for more information, an error occurs during the installation of assembly (8.0.50727.6229)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to install the 64-bit on a 32-bit Windows O/S?

Comment: Both dialogs provide functionality to copy the contents. Don't post screenshots of text, when you can **easily** post text instead. Text is discoverable in text searches.

Comment: Rawns no i have windows 10 pro 64 bit version

Answer (score 0):

Taken from here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_programs/error-1935an-error-occurred-during-the/7105ee7e-ab45-4bd2-b5db-a3e9002f7f9e

If you receive a 1935 error when you try to install software, the Windows file system transaction log has become corrupted. The transaction log is used by the Windows file system to recover when a file error occurs. It can also happen if there is an error with the installation of .netframework.

**Step 1: To correct this install error, you need to clear the log.**

- Open an Administrator command prompt: Right-click Start > All
  Programs > Accessories > Command Prompt and select "Run as
  Administrator" and click "Allow" for the elevation prompt
- In the command prompt, type the command below:

`fsutil resource setautoreset true C:\`

- This assumes that C: is the drive in which Vista is installed. If it
  is installed on another drive like D:, please change the drive letter
  appropriately.
- Reboot the system.
- Install the software and check.

**Step 2: Check if you are able to install in clean boot.**

“How to perform Clean Boot” http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135

Note: Please ensure that the computer is set to start as usual by following the step 7 from the article.

**Step 3: Repair .net framework and check.**

Repair the Microsoft .NET Framework installation

To do this, follow these steps:

- Click Start, click Control Panel, and then click Add or Remove Programs.
- In the Currently installed programs list, click Microsoft .NET Framework, and then click Change/Remove.
- Click Repair, and then click Next.

Comment: This is not error 1935 so this is unlikely to be the correct answer. But good on you for attributing the original link